# Custom component with multiple items

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to create my own custom tabs component that would allow the same XML structure as Nativescript TabView:

```xml
<Tabs>
    <Tabs.items>
        <Tabs title="Tab 1">
            <Tabs.view>
                <!-- First tab content  -->
            </Tabs.view>
        </Tabs>
        <Tabs title="Tab 2">
            <Tabs.view>
                <!-- Second tab content  -->
            </Tabs.view>
        </Tabs>
        <Tabs title="Tab 3">
            <Tabs.view>
                <!-- Third tab content  -->
            </Tabs.view>
        </Tabs>
    </Tabs.items>
</Tabs>
```

The reason I don't want to use the existing one is that I would like to use this custom component inside each ListView item and the existing one is designed to be used as a full page component and using it inside list items would be cumbersome. As with the existing component tapping a tab title would load the corresponding view and unload the old one. I don't need any animation there and don't want to use Android ViewPager and iOS UITabBarController, but just Nativescript views as tabs content.

I would appreciate if someone could share an idea or link on how to builds such a custom tabs component with Nativescript.

Comment: Perhaps you can use`SegmentedBar` and show/hide the content views https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/ui-category/segmented-bar/segmented-bar-views/segmented-bar-views.component.html#L3-L14

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the comment, but I'm looking to create a component. Plugin makers do this somehow right? Although Nativescript lacks such a documentation unfortunately, I still would like an elegant component, rather than a lame thing with SegmentedBar and hiding/showing views:)